# SQL database repetative value sum

Tags: postgresql

i have a database table with repetitive values in every cell and also same values separated by commas in particular cell, if i need to count all the occurrences of particular name (ex : Facebook) what query i must use(amazon red shift)

Comment: No query, no info = no answer.  Please update with the information you think someone would need to help you.

Answer (score 0):

A typical SQL query would be:

```sql
select count(1) from table t1 where t1.column_name = 'Facebook';
```

This is if the data cells contain just that word exactly.

Or you might have:

```sql
select count(1) from table t1 where t1.column_name like '%Facebook%';
```

This is if you want to count rows containing word 'Facebook' (among other strings).